# Can open RTSP camera stream in FFMPEG but not in Gstreamer rtspsrc: Bad Request (400)

Tags: ffmpeg, camera, gstreamer, rtsp

I have a Panasonic WV-SW559 camera set up as an RTSP stream.

VLC can perfectly open the RTSP stream and display it, as well as FFMPEG.
However, when I try to set up a simple gstreamer pipeline, it does not want to open.
I execute the following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc --gst-debug=rtspsrc:5 location="rtspt://admin:12345@192.168.2.148:554/MediaInput/h264/stream_1" ! fakesink
```

after which I get the following output:

```
0:00:00.063009504 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:8617:gst_rtspsrc_uri_set_uri:<rtspsrc0> parsing URI
0:00:00.063074922 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:8624:gst_rtspsrc_uri_set_uri:<rtspsrc0> configuring URI
0:00:00.063111485 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:8640:gst_rtspsrc_uri_set_uri:<rtspsrc0> set uri: rtspt://admin:12345@192.168.2.148:554/MediaInput/h264/stream_1
0:00:00.063136642 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:8642:gst_rtspsrc_uri_set_uri:<rtspsrc0> request uri is: rtsp://192.168.2.148:554/MediaInput/h264/stream_1
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.064752828 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:8391:gst_rtspsrc_start:<rtspsrc0> starting
0:00:00.064910956 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5567:gst_rtspsrc_loop_send_cmd:<rtspsrc0> sending cmd OPEN
0:00:00.064938405 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5598:gst_rtspsrc_loop_send_cmd:<rtspsrc0> not interrupting busy cmd unknown
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
0:00:00.065145962 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:8346:gst_rtspsrc_thread:<rtspsrc0> got command OPEN
0:00:00.065182682 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4748:gst_rtspsrc_connection_flush:<rtspsrc0> set flushing 0
0:00:00.065214662 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4614:gst_rtsp_conninfo_connect:<rtspsrc0> creating connection (rtspt://admin:12345@192.168.2.148:554/MediaInput/h264/stream_1)...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
0:00:00.065652329 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4625:gst_rtsp_conninfo_connect:<rtspsrc0> sanitized uri rtsp://192.168.2.148:554/MediaInput/h264/stream_1
0:00:00.065710611 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4659:gst_rtsp_conninfo_connect:<rtspsrc0> connecting (rtspt://admin:12345@192.168.2.148:554/MediaInput/h264/stream_1)...
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtspt://admin:12345@192.168.2.148:554/MediaInput/h264/stream_1
0:00:00.081446411 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7342:gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp:<rtspsrc0> create options... (async)
0:00:00.081494537 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7351:gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp:<rtspsrc0> send options...
0:00:00.081575581 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:476:default_before_send:<rtspsrc0> default handler
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
0:00:00.081618707 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:476:default_before_send:<rtspsrc0> default handler
0:00:00.081671521 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5964:gst_rtspsrc_try_send:<rtspsrc0> sending message
0:00:00.088226524 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5866:gst_rtsp_src_receive_response:<rtspsrc0> received response message
0:00:00.088280901 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5885:gst_rtsp_src_receive_response:<rtspsrc0> got response message 400
0:00:00.088321370 23339   0x55cd528a30 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:6161:gst_rtspsrc_send:<rtspsrc0> error: Unhandled error
0:00:00.088335798 23339   0x55cd528a30 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:6161:gst_rtspsrc_send:<rtspsrc0> error: Bad Request (400)
0:00:00.088454915 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7514:gst_rtspsrc_retrieve_sdp:<rtspsrc0> free connection
0:00:00.088526323 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4715:gst_rtsp_conninfo_close:<rtspsrc0> closing connection...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Unhandled error
Additional debug info:
gstrtspsrc.c(6161): gst_rtspsrc_send (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0:
Bad Request (400)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
0:00:00.088648097 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4721:gst_rtsp_conninfo_close:<rtspsrc0> freeing connection...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
0:00:00.088699505 23339   0x55cd528a30 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7548:gst_rtspsrc_open:<rtspsrc0> can't get sdp
0:00:00.088747891 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:8346:gst_rtspsrc_thread:<rtspsrc0> got command LOOP
0:00:00.088786121 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4748:gst_rtspsrc_connection_flush:<rtspsrc0> set flushing 0
0:00:00.088812372 23339   0x55cd528a30 WARN                 rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5628:gst_rtspsrc_loop:<rtspsrc0> we are not connected
0:00:00.088832841 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5636:gst_rtspsrc_loop:<rtspsrc0> pausing task, reason flushing
0:00:00.088855394 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5567:gst_rtspsrc_loop_send_cmd:<rtspsrc0> sending cmd WAIT
0:00:00.088885863 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5585:gst_rtspsrc_loop_send_cmd:<rtspsrc0> cancel previous request LOOP
0:00:00.088905135 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5593:gst_rtspsrc_loop_send_cmd:<rtspsrc0> connection flush busy LOOP
0:00:00.088923000 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4748:gst_rtspsrc_connection_flush:<rtspsrc0> set flushing 1
0:00:00.088996595 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5567:gst_rtspsrc_loop_send_cmd:<rtspsrc0> sending cmd CLOSE
0:00:00.089030346 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5593:gst_rtspsrc_loop_send_cmd:<rtspsrc0> connection flush busy WAIT
0:00:00.089045971 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4748:gst_rtspsrc_connection_flush:<rtspsrc0> set flushing 1
0:00:00.089085660 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:8346:gst_rtspsrc_thread:<rtspsrc0> got command CLOSE
0:00:00.089109462 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4748:gst_rtspsrc_connection_flush:<rtspsrc0> set flushing 0
0:00:00.089129619 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7569:gst_rtspsrc_close:<rtspsrc0> TEARDOWN...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
0:00:00.089211288 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7574:gst_rtspsrc_close:<rtspsrc0> not ready, doing cleanup
0:00:00.089263997 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7637:gst_rtspsrc_close:<rtspsrc0> closing connection...
0:00:00.089300769 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:8422:gst_rtspsrc_stop:<rtspsrc0> stopping
0:00:00.089330926 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5567:gst_rtspsrc_loop_send_cmd:<rtspsrc0> sending cmd WAIT
0:00:00.089333374 23339   0x55cd528a30 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:2058:gst_rtspsrc_cleanup:<rtspsrc0> cleanup
0:00:00.089354260 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:5593:gst_rtspsrc_loop_send_cmd:<rtspsrc0> connection flush busy CLOSE
0:00:00.089419939 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:4748:gst_rtspsrc_connection_flush:<rtspsrc0> set flushing 1
0:00:00.089493430 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7569:gst_rtspsrc_close:<rtspsrc0> TEARDOWN...
0:00:00.089520931 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7574:gst_rtspsrc_close:<rtspsrc0> not ready, doing cleanup
0:00:00.089539212 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:7637:gst_rtspsrc_close:<rtspsrc0> closing connection...
0:00:00.089556192 23339   0x55cd6d9180 DEBUG                rtspsrc gstrtspsrc.c:2058:gst_rtspsrc_cleanup:<rtspsrc0> cleanup
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Does anyone have an idea on why this could occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Panasonic WV-NW502S, and I am having exactly the same problem when I try to set up a RTSP stream using gstreamer. Some one suggested it might has something to do with RTSP server configuration, so now I am trying to find more specific information in that direction.

Update: my problem is solved with the command:
sudo apt remove gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly

I saw this solution several times in other posts like [this one](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/rtsp-gstreamer-simple-recieve-and-store-in-file/157535/14) and [this one](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/gstrtspsrc-could-not-receive-message/142377/11), but I didn't try it because some people posted it didn't work for them. I finally gave it a try, and it fixed my problem.

Comment: Thanks, removing plugins-ugly also resolved the problem for me.

Comment: thanks , removing ugly plugin resolved the problem for`panasonic wv sp781l` camera also.

Answer (score 0):

Not that `rtspsrc` has a `user-id` and `user-pw` property to set user and password for authentication.